# ReferenceError: 'username' is not defined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to pass data to home page after a user login in ionic. In home page if I did this:

```
  ionViewDidLoad() {
   console.log(this.navParams.get('username'));
 }
```

The username would be displayed. But if I do this:

```
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,  public  
navParams:NavParams,     
  public loadingCtrl:LoadingController) {
   this.username = this.navParams.get('username');
    }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
      console.log(username);
    }
```

The error below is being displayed:

> ReferenceError: 'username' is not defined

I already did this:

```
  data:any;
  username:any;
  members: Array<any>;
  loader: any;
```

I want to be able to call the username anywhere in the page.

Comment: In `ionViewDidLoad` your have did mistake in console.log change this.username instead of username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .html file 
the input field that you use to for username

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="username">
```

and in

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {
  console.log(this.username);
}
```